# change case in xslt and store in hyperlink

Tags: xslt

I had change the case of alphabets in xslt and display it using following code:

```
<xsl:param name="character" 
    select="/Properties/Data/External/Parameters/Datum[@Name='fChar']"/>

<xsl:value-of select="
    translate(
        $character,
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        )
    "/>
```

But I want to change the case of letter and store in href of anchor tag.

My Previous hyperlink code is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="pagination1">$GOOD_PREFIX[]list-
<xsl:value-of select="
    /Properties/Data/External/Parameters/Datum[@Name='fChar']"/>

<a href="{$pagination1}"><strong>« Previous/strong>/a>
```

Let me Know to clarify something.

Comment: You may need indent your question better to make it more readable. And try to accept more answers

Comment: how to use translate function of xslt 1.0 in anchor tag. Kindly provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="character" select="'OHWAIT'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="pagination1" select="
            translate(
                $character,
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                )
            "/>
        <a href="$GOOD_PREFIX[]list-{$pagination1}">
            <strong>« Previous</strong>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to any XML document (not used) it provides this correct result:

```
<a href="$GOOD_PREFIX[]list-ohwait"><strong>« Previous</strong></a>
```